# Matplotlib text not showing up in pandas plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to add a text annotation to a pandas plot by giving coordinates in a relative range of 0-1 for the axes, but currently the text is not showing up.  Here is some sample code and the resulting plot:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = sns.load_dataset('iris')
df['sepal_length'].plot()
plt.text(0.7, 0.7, 'test')
plt.show()
```

[image: pandas plot]

I'm using versions:
pandas: 0.24.2
matplotlib: 3.0.3

on Ubuntu 18.

The annotate() function also doesn't seem to work.

Any clues as to why the text doesn't show up?

Comment: `(0.7, 0.7)` is outside of your plot range. Use maybe `(20, 7)` instead.

Comment: @wordsforthewise Agreed.

Answer (score 4):

OK, thanks to @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I was misunderstanding the arguments of plt.text().  By default, the x and y coordinates are in the 'data' dimension.  To instead use the range of 0-1 for the axes, you can  do:

```
ax = df['sepal_length'].plot()
plt.text(0.1, 0.7, 'test', transform=ax.transAxes)
```

This isn't super clear from the documentation (especially options for the 'transform' arg), but it's in an example: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html#matplotlib.pyplot.text

Answer (score 0):

Because the boundaries of your plot exceed the values you have passed, you should try passing different parameters such as:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = sns.load_dataset('iris')
df['sepal_length'].plot()
plt.text(70,7, 'test')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, the test point you are using is outside of your plotted range. Test a point inside the range and it should work as expected.

Here is the test point (60,5)

[image]